# SQL error 'ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)' for DELETE function

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to delete rows that exist in both temp_abstract table and abstract table.

```
DELETE FROM temp_abstracts 
WHERE application_id IN
    (SELECT temp_abstracts.application_id, abstracts.application_id 
    FROM temp_abstracts INNER JOIN abstracts 
    ON temp_abstracts.application_id=abstracts.application_id)
    ;
```

When I just run what's inside the parentheses it returns what I want, but adding a delete from where seems to throw this error. Any help?

Comment: you can not select multiple column inside IN clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` instead :

```
DELETE ta
FROM temp_abstracts ta 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM abstracts a WHERE a.application_id = ta.application_id);
```

Sub-query will return only one expression while using `IN` OR `NOT IN`.